# DYALOG APL, Connect to SQL Server using .NET and load a DataTable with data using SqlConnection

Tags: apl, dyalog

DYALOG APL, Connect to MS SQL Server using .NET and load a DataTable with data using SqlConnection.

I do not want to use SQAPL.
I want to use DataTable as they can be used as data sources to GUI components, and want to use DataTable methods and libraries I have experience with.
SQAPL also needs DSN on client machine if I am not mistaken.

I want to connect to SQL Server using .NET and load a DataTable with data, using the `SqlConnection` class.

I do not mind using an older version .Net such as 4.5

```
      ]version
 Dyalog  18.2.45405 64-bit Unicode, BuildID 8ebc0eba            
 OS      Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 (10.0.19045) 64-bit  
 Link    3.0.19                                                 
 SALT    2.9                                                    
 UCMD    2.51                                                   
 .NET    .NET Framework 4.8.9166.0                              
 WS      18.2
```

```
      ⎕USING←'' 'System.Data.SqlClient'
      sqlConnection1 ← ⎕NEW SqlConnection VarConnectionString
VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: SqlConnection
```

Comment: What is `SQAPL`?

Comment: And what are the funny boxes in your code block?

Comment: And what language are you writing in, and why do you think it can use .NET components?

Comment: Dyalog APL is very good at using .NET components. See https://docs.dyalog.com/latest/dotNET%20Core%20Interface%20Guide.pdf

Comment: Have you tried [reading the friendly manual](https://docs.dyalog.com/latest/SQL%20Interface%20Guide.pdf)? _It is possible to connect to databases for which there is no pre-defined data source – see the
description of the SQA.Connect function, in particular the DriverOptions parameter._ The implication being that you can pass in ODBC connection properties like `Server`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That's the SQAPL OP *doesn't* want to use.

Comment: To a Dyalog APL user, this question is perfectly clear, with almost all the detail one could wish for. @MikeChris Can you add Dyalog and .NET versions to your post? Type `]version` into the session to get the info.

Comment: @DaleK Dyalog APL is full of funny symbols, inlcuding `⎕`, called "quad". It is correctly rendered as a box.

Comment: You probably don't need/want to tag sql server... you're just attracting experts who cannot help. Dyalog and Apl seem the only relevant tags.

Comment: @Adám I was disproving OP's comment, _SQAPL also needs DSN on client machine if I am not mistaken._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With .NET Framework (4.8) it is very straightforward:

```
      ⎕USING←'System.Data.SqlClient,System.Data.dll'
      c←⎕NEW SqlConnection (⊂'Server=myServerName,myPortNumber;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;')
      c.⎕NL -3 ⍝ Methodlist
BeginTransaction  ChangeDatabase  ChangePassword  ClearAllPools  ClearPool  Close  CreateCommand  CreateObjRef  Dispose EnlistDistributedTransaction  EnlistTransaction  Equals  GetHashCode  GetLifetimeService  GetSchema  GetType  InitializeLifetimeService  Open  OpenAsync  ReferenceEquals  RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders  ResetStatistics  RetrieveStatistics  ToString
```

---

> SQAPL also needs DSN on client machine if I am not mistaken.

SQAPL does NOT require defining a DSN; you can provide a connect string instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam, Success !!!
So the SQLClient Namespace is in System.Data.dll
I finally got the DataTable.

Answer (score 4):

With the Help of Adám, this is the code I used to get the DataTable from MS SQL Server.

```
⎕USING←'System.Data.SqlClient,System.Data.dll'
⎕USING←'System.Data,System.Data.dll'
c←⎕NEW SqlClient.SqlConnection (⊂'Server= 1.1.1.2;Database=dbName;User 
Id=sa;Password=sdsdedf;')
sqlcmd ← ⎕NEW SqlClient.SqlCommand
sqlAddapter ← ⎕NEW SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
sqlAddapter.FillLoadOption ← LoadOption.OverwriteChanges
sqlcmd.CommandTimeout←2400
sqlcmd.Connection←c
sqlcmd.CommandType←  CommandType.Text
sqlcmd.CommandText←  'Select top(10) * from Companies'
sqlAddapter.SelectCommand←sqlcmd
tmpDataset ← ⎕NEW DataSet 
sqlAddapter.SelectCommand←sqlcmd
sqlAddapter.Fill tmpDataset 'Table'
sqlAddapter.Dispose
tblCompanies ← tmpDataset.Tables[0]
```